# Ember's 'observes' throws assertion error, while computed property does not?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an component that throws an error when I use `observes`, but not when I use `property` in the `displayPages` computed property:

```
App.ExampleComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName : 'ul',
    classNames : [ 'pagination' ],
    current : 1,
    modelName : null,
    meta : null,

    actions : {
        next : function() {
            var current = this.get('current');
            this.set('current', parseInt(current, 10) + 1);
        },

        previous : function() {
            var current = this.get('current');
            this.set('current', parseInt(current, 10) - 1);
        }
    },

    updateMeta : function() {       
        this.set('meta', new Number(Math.random()));

    }.observes('current').on('init'),

    currentPage : function() {
        return Number(this.get('current'));
    }.property('current'),

    displayPages : function() {

        // complex logic lives here, so I used "observes" instead of "property"

        console.log('Im invoked the first time meta is set, but not on subsequent changes');

        var result = [];
        return result;

    }.property('meta')

});
```

If I change the `observes` and use `property` instead it works properly. But the `displayPages` property contains complex logic so I want to use `observes` as per documentation guidelines:

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/what-do-i-use-when/

If I replace that `.property('meta')` and replace it with `.observes('meta')`, then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed function
```

The question is... **why is that?**

I don't think I understand the different between `observes` and `property`, but reading the docs didn't help much in this case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed properties return a value.  Observes fires a function when a value changes.   In other words, observes doesn't return a value.

You probably are trying to iterate your observes method, and Ember is yelling saying, I expected an array in order to iterate, and you passed me a function.

Example showing this: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tariliya/1/edit

You should be using a computed property.  It will update every time a dependent property changes.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Maybe this would be included in the doc page I pointed in the post. I'll open a ticket suggesting it. Thank you!